# How to password protect couchdb web interface (futon)?

Tags: couchdb

I would like to know how to password protect couchdb web interface in a production server?

What's the best method?

Thanks

So far I tried with .htaccess, although it is still not protecting:

```
  AuthUserFile /home/dir/htpassword/.htpasswd
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "CouchDB Admin Interface"  
  Require valid-user
```

Comment: Added an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, CouchDB is the server, and it doesn't support .htaccess as far as I'm concerned. You can, of course, proxy it through Apache, but the best solution would probably be to use the built-in authentication methods of Couchdb.